# Query where NOT NULL but only if NOT used as a FK

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

```
area
-----
id           BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
deleted_at   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE   DEFAULT NULL
```

and

```
registration
-----
area_id   BIGINT   REFERENCES area(id) NOT NULL
```

I want to get all records from `area` which have `deleted_at IS NULL` and the ones that can have `deleted_at is NOT NULL` **but** are present as a FK in the `registration`.

```
SELECT * FROM area
  JOIN registration AS reg 
    ON reg.area_id=area.id
 WHERE area.deleted_at IS NULL;
```

will omit the `area` records which are FKs in `registration` but have been marked as "deleted".

Adding an `AND` clause regarding the `deleted_at` column in the `JOIN ON` clause doesn't make sense, since it will only strip out valid records.

I can't quite wrap it around my head, since the two `where` conditions kind of contradict each other.

Comment: I do not think `IS NOT NULL` would be the same as `<> TRUE`...

Comment: @wildplasser, the `deleted_at` is of type `timestamp`. It's not boolean. I updated my post.

Comment: Oops, I misread.(thought it was an is_deleted flag) Sorry!

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to add your table's definition to the question? (and restrict the text to your actual intentions and the unwanted behaviour)

Comment: @wildplasser, good idea. I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM area
    LEFT JOIN registration AS reg ON reg.area_id = area.id
  WHERE (area.deleted_at IS NULL) <> (reg.area_id IS NOT NULL)
```

The `LEFT JOIN` would list  all `area` rows, even without a matching row from `registration`. (Resulting `NULL` values for those rows.)
The `WHERE` clause makes sure that both of the fields are not `NULL`s at the same time.

Comment: Actually, your where clause is making sure that both fields are either null or non-null at the same time. If `(area.deleted_at IS NULL)` is true then `(reg.area_id IS NOT NULL)` must be false, therefore `(reg.area_id IS NULL)` must be true.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your asking for.  When you use left join it data fields for registration will show up as null where they are not present in registration table.

```
select * from area
left join registration as reg
on reg.area_id= area.id
where area.deleted_at is null or reg.area_id is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- I need (0) all area records EXCEPT the ones where (1) deleted_at IS NOT NULL
-- AND (2) are NOT present as FKs in registration.

SELECT * FROM area a
WHERE NOT(
   a.deleted_at IS NOT NULL -- (1)
   AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *                -- (2)
        FROM registration r 
        WHERE r.area_id=a.id
        )
     );
```

---

Note: your textual phrasing is confusing: `EXCEPT a AND b` could mean two things

---

And, after the rephrasing of the question:

---

```
-- I want to get (0) all records from area (1) which have deleted_at IS NULL (1a)
-- and (2) the ones that can have deleted_at is NOT NULL but are present as a FK in the registration.

SELECT * FROM area a
WHERE a.deleted_at IS NULL -- (1)
   OR a.deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (                (1a)  
        SELECT *                -- (2)
        FROM registration r 
        WHERE r.area_id=a.id
        );
```

---

If I understand correctly, you mean *plus the ones* at *(1a)* : if so, the **and** in *(1a)* is translated into an **or**

Comment: I'm am pretty sure OP needs `deleted_at is NOT NULL and NOT EXISTS (<reference>)`. Those are the ones marked as deleted *and* not referenced.

Comment: Basically, I don't care. He could express himself better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply searching for the following query?

```
SELECT * FROM Area
LEFT OUTER JOIN registration on id = area_id
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL OR area_id IS NOT NULL
```

This will return the same `area.id` multiple times if `registration.area_id` is not unique though (since you have no `UNIQUE` constraints).
If that is a problem, you may want the following query instead.

```
SELECT * FROM Area
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL OR id IN (SELECT area_id FROM registration)
```

Or this, built with a `COUNT`:

```
SELECT id, deleted_at, COUNT(*) FROM Area
LEFT OUTER JOIN registration on id = area_id
WHERE (deleted_at IS NULL or area_id IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY id, deleted_at
```